# Can we convert nitrogen from the air into liquid nitrogen?

Tags: gas-laws

Is it possible to convert the nitrogen that surrounds us, into liquid nitrogen?

If so, how? If not, why not?

Thx

Comment: Yes e. g. http://www.elan2.com/

Comment: If a question is asked on Chemistry SE site, then, in contrary to sites like Quora, it is expected from the author to elaborate the topic of the question by doing at least basic own topic review, writing what he/she has found and understood, and what is the stumble stone. The quick questions without explicitly expressed particular effort are not very welcome, and may be closed. A poster should not expect respondents would give it more effort then he/she has explicitly spent on it him/herself.

Comment: [Linde cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hampson%E2%80%93Linde_cycle).

Comment: @Poutnik this was not a homework question. It was just out of curiosity :)

Comment: @cbracketdash  "As homework is considered literal homework, self-study questions, puzzles, worked examples etc."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, why not? If you look at the [Wikipedia article of liquid nitrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_nitrogen), it says:

> **Liquid nitrogen is produced commercially from the cryogenic
> distillation of liquefied air or from the liquefaction of pure
> nitrogen derived from air using pressure swing adsorption**. An air
> compressor is used to compress filtered air to high pressure; the
> high-pressure gas is cooled back to ambient temperature, and allowed
> to expand to a low pressure. The expanding air cools greatly (the
> Joule–Thomson effect), and oxygen, nitrogen, and argon are separated
> by further stages of expansion and distillation. Small-scale
> production of liquid nitrogen is easily achieved using this principle.

But first, you have to separate nitrogen from other components in air like oxygen, argon, water vapor, carbon dioxide. It is done though either of three methods: Cryogenic Air Separation, Absorption, and Membrane Diffusion. The process by which liquid nitrogen is formed from its gaseous state is more or less the same but the methods become different at how the gases are separated.

1. Cryogenic Air Separation

The air is sent to a container. Water vapor and carbon dioxide is separated by lowering the temperature in the container and freezing them to the walls of the container which are drained and vented. The left over elements (nitrogen, argon, and oxygen) are sent on to another container which is warmed at $\pu{-185 ^\circ C}$(b.p of oxygen and argon) which forces the two elements to the bottom of the container. Nitrogen is left in a gaseous state which is recovered from the separation Unit by sending to a cryorefrigerator where it is drawn off as a cryogenic liquid at about $\pu{-321°F}$.

The cryorefrigerator consists of a cold head, helium compressor package and a pair of stainless steel flexible helium lines. The cold head is mounted into the top of the liquid tank (dewar). The cold head extends down into the neck of the liquid tank for the purpose of cooling the nitrogen entering the liquid tank to $\pu{77 K}$ ($\pu{-196 °C}$). The nitrogen gas liquefies on contact with the cold head heat exchanger. The liquefied nitrogen drips off the heat exchanger down into the liquid nitrogen inside the dewar.

2. Absorption process

This method takes advantage of chemical properties of the element and compresses air through absorbent materials like activated carbon  which absorb different elements in the air and leave a sample that is of a majority composed of nitrogen.

3. Membrane diffusion

This method takes advantage of the fact that different materials diffuse through polymer lined tubes at different rates.  Specifically nitrogen and argon diffuse at a slower rate than oxygen and carbon dioxide.

Here is a homemade liquid nitrogen generator: https://www.instructables.com/id/Homemade-liquid-nitrogen-generator/

**References**

1. http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/212_spring2011.web.dir/Benjamin_Lauritzen/Slide2.htm
2. http://www.amitlabs.com/liquid-nitrogen.html
3. https://www.mvsengg.com/products/nitrogen/liquid-nitrogen/
4. https://www.trimechindia.com/psa-nitrogen-plant.html